# sicktoolbox baud rate

Tags: ros, sicklms, ubuntu, sicktoolbox-wrapper, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using UDOO board and a sick lms 200. I get an error when i run the sicktoolbox_wrapper which says "failed to detect baud rate". If not that the program waits indefintely at startup.

> ***  Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
> Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0

the program waits here forever or it says "failed to detect the baud rate". I've tried the same serial to usb converter cable on my x86 machine and it works perfectly. I sometimes get the following error

" *** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
Device opened!
Attempting to start buffer monitor...
Buffer monitor started!
Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
Failed to set requested baud rate...
Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
Checking 19200bps...
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: Unable to set device attributes!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: Unable to set device attributes!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: Unable to set device attributes!
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/sicktoolbox_wrapper/sicklms: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/sicktoolbox_wrapper/sicklms: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192103/sicktoolbox-baud-rate/) by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-06**:
You have **two** open questions and an open bug about your problems already. Please update those before asking a new question.

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-06**:
sorryy.. forgot to update them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yup got it working. I ripped open the usb-serial converter that i had been using and turns out the chip inside was of some chinese make and wasnt compatible with the ftdi_sio module. After a while i remembered that i had an old serial to ttl logic converter which also happens to be a serial-usb converter. It uses a silabs chip compatible with cp210x. Although i was quite skeptical since it uses a max232 IC  to convert the serial signal to ttl levels. But anyhow i connected it and it worked right away.

On a side note though, will the max 232 IC cause me to miss some scans??

---

Originally posted by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) with karma: 63 on 2014-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
[ INFO] [1410107452.536568609]: Variant setup not requested or identical to actual (180, 0.500000)
[ INFO] [1410107452.536760382]: Measuring units setup not requested or identical to actual ('Millimeters (mm)')
Requesting partial scan data stream..

Why does it say partial scan?..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-07**:
Most of the max232 series of ICs have a rated baud rate. As long as you stay below that, you shouldn't lose any data.

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
[ INFO] [1410107452.536568609]: Variant setup not requested or identical to actual (180, 0.500000)
[ INFO] [1410107452.536760382]: Measuring units setup not requested or identical to actual ('Millimeters (mm)')
Requesting partial scan data stream.. why am i getting this??..

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-07**:
I'm not sure what that message means. It may be normal. Do you think it's causing problems?

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
No not really.. hopefully wont be a problem. Just wanted your say on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not too sure about the baud rate detection, but it looks like the driver is crashing due to an ABI mismatch:

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/sicktoolbox_wrapper/sicklms: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/sicktoolbox_wrapper/sicklms: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
```

I would start with an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to install the latest version of the driver, and see if it still has this problem.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
i did the upgrade.. the ABI mismatch doesnt occur now but the baudrate issue is still present. I have checked the cable manually (using multimeter) as well it seems to be receiving the signals properly.Let me show you the output of dmesg | grep tty it might give u a better overview of the situation.

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
[  421.762333] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: error from flowcontrol urb
[ 2290.997438] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: ftdi_set_termios FAILED to set databits/stopbits/parity
[ 2291.005463] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: ftdi_set_termios urb failed to set baudrate
[ 2291.012692] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: urb failed to clear flow control

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-07**:
This still looks like a driver/hardware problem. The only relevant post I've been able to find suggests using a powered USB hub: http://gumstix.8.x6.nabble.com/FTDI-USB-to-serial-converter-problem-ftdi-set-termios-FAILED-to-set-databits-stopbits-parity-td4966979.html

**Comment by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) on 2014-09-07**:
okay. I'll try doing that. Thanks alot for your help ahendrix. :) .